# Widget has too many database calls? Need a refactor suggestion

Tags: magento-1.9, database, widgets, widget, pagespeed

I'm using Magento 1.9.3 and I have a theme that is loading very slow. After a debug I found that on the home page for example I'm loading New Products widget, Featured Poducts Widget, Sale Products Widget and Manufacturer Products Widget.

If I commented these widgets from the CMS Page, the website loaded instantly. With them active, the website has a delay of 5 seconds.

I have the following manufacturers widget:

```
<?php
$maufacturers = Mage::getModel('manufacturer/manufacturer')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status',Array('eq'=>1))->setPageSize(15)->setCurPage(1);    
?> 
<div id="manufacture-logo" class="manufacture_products">
 <div class="category-title"><h2><span><?php echo $this->getHeading(); ?></span></h2></div>
     <?php $_collectionSize = $maufacturers->count() ?>

    <?php 
        $sliderFor =5;
        $productCount = $_collectionSize; 
    ?>  
    <?php if ($productCount >= $sliderFor): ?>
        <div class="customNavigation">
            <a class="btn prev">&nbsp;</a>
            <a class="btn next">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>  
    <?php endif; ?> 
        <ul class="<?php if ($productCount >= $sliderFor){?>product-carousel<?php }else{?>products-grid<?php }?>" id="<?php if ($productCount >= $sliderFor){?>brand-carousel<?php }else{?>brand-grid<?php }?>">        
    <?php foreach($maufacturers as $manufacturer): ?>       
        <?php if(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')->setAttribute(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product', Mage::getStoreConfig('manufacturer/general/attribute_code'))))->getOptionText($manufacturer->getManufacturerName())): ?>

           <li class="<?php if ($productCount >= $sliderFor){?>slider-item<?php }else{?>product-items<?php }?> item">
                <div class="product-block">
                <div class="product-block-inner">

                    <a href="<?php echo $manufacturer->getUrl();?>">
                        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setmanufacturerimage($manufacturer->getFilename())->setListPageFlag(1)->setTemplate('manufacturer/manufacturer_resize.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
                    </a>

                    <?php if($this->displayName()):?>
                    <div class="manufacturer-name">
                        <a href="<?php echo $manufacturer->getUrl(); ?>">  <?php echo Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')->setAttribute(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load(Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product', Mage::getStoreConfig('manufacturer/general/attribute_code'))))->getOptionText($manufacturer->getManufacturerName()) ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div><!-- End div class product-block-->
                </div><!-- End div class product-block-inner -->
         </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
 <span  class="brand_default_width" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"></span>
```

Am I right to say that there are DB calls inside the Foreach? I know this is a bad code.

Below you'll find the code for the Featured Products Widget:

```
<div class="featured-products">
 <div class="category-title"><h2><?php echo $this->__($this->getBlockLabel()) ?></h2></div>
 <div class="featured-products-inner">


<?php if(!$this->getProductCollection()->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?> 
<?php if (($_productCollection = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_productCollection->getSize()): ?>


    <?php // Grid Mode ?>
    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>



    <?php 
        $sliderFor =4;
        $productCount = $_collectionSize; 
    ?>

    <?php if ($productCount >= $sliderFor): ?>
        <div class="customNavigation">
            <a class="btn prev">prev</a>
            <a class="btn next">next</a>
        </div>  
    <?php endif; ?> 

        <ul class="<?php if ($productCount >= $sliderFor){?>product-carousel<?php }else{?>products-grid<?php }?>" id="<?php if ($productCount >= $sliderFor){?>featured-carousel<?php }else{?>featured-grid<?php }?>">

            <?php  $i = 0; $row = 0; foreach ($_productCollection->getItems() as $_product):  ?>

                <?php
                    $stock_text = $_product->getStockText();
                    $faraCos = $_product->getFaraCos();
               ?>
                 <li class="item <?php if ($productCount >= $sliderFor){?>slider-item<?php }else{?>product-items<?php }?>"> 

                    <div class="product-block">
        <div class="product-block-inner">
                    <div class="product-image-block-inner"> 
                <div class="product-image-block"> 
                        <?php if($this->helper('framework')->isNewProduct($_product)):?>
                            <div class="new-label"><?php echo $this->__('New') ?></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if($this->helper('framework')->isSpecialProduct($_product)):?>
                        <div class="sale-label"><?php echo $this->__('Sale') ?></div>
                       <?php endif; ?>


         <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
        <?php $productId = $_product->getId();  $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); ?>
        <img class="remover-image" id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(178,248); ?>" alt="" />
        <img  class="hover-image" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(178,248); ?>" width="178" height="248" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'thumbnail'), null, true) ?>" />
         </a>



        </div>

    </div>

                    <div class="product_desc">

                    <h2 class="product-name" ><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?>">
                        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getName()); ?>
                    </a></h2> 
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?> 
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>

                    <?php if ($stock_text==201) { ?> 
                            <div class="ribbon-wrapper-green"><div class="ribbon-green">în stoc</div></div>
                    <?php } elseif ($stock_text==202) { ?>
                            <div class="ribbon-wrapper-red"><div class="ribbon-red">stoc epuizat</div></div>
                    <?php }  elseif ($stock_text==200) { ?>
                            <div class="ribbon-wrapper-limitat"><div class="ribbon-limitat">stoc limitat</div></div>
                    <?php }  elseif ($stock_text==219) { ?>
                            <div class="ribbon-wrapper-comanda"><div class="ribbon-comanda">la comanda</div></div>
                    <?php } elseif ($stock_text==226) { ?>
                            <div class="ribbon-wrapper-stocfurnizor"><div class="ribbon-stocfurnizor">stoc furnizor</div></div>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php /*?> <div class="description"><?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?></div><?php */?>
                    </div> 

                    <div class="product_hover-block">
                    <div class="actions">

                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <?php if (!$faraCos && $stock_text!=202): ?>
                                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><a href="https://www.distributieutilaje.ro/contact">Contactati-ne</a></span></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>  

                        <?php if (!$faraCos && $stock_text!=202): ?>
                            <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            </ul>       
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div><!-- End div class product-block-inner -->
    </div><!-- End div class product-block -->

               </li>        
    <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul> 

     <span class="featured_default_width" style="display:none; visibility:hidden"></span>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>  
</div> 
</div>
```

Am I right to say that this code is bad? That there are database calls inside the foreach? What would you refactor in case of the Featured Produts widget? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To load home page quickly and you want to display more than 2 widget then you should use ajax call for each and every widget for home page.
For example: once the home page loaded, you should fire ajax call and render response html for particular block/widget. Please check below URL to get more idea.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876725/magento-product-listing-using-ajax

Answer (score 1):

This would require a deeper code trace (and probably some adjustments in block classes), but a quick tip could be...

Try to avoid loading the full product object in a product list, as it happens in the second piece of code you have posted... that would free memory & make things faster

If you loose some valuable content after doing that then you'd find which attributes are needed in your templates & add them to product list, through backoffice **Attributes Management**, using `used_in_product_listing` attribute